# Laravel AJAX call with method PUT

Tags: ajax, laravel

so what I'm trying to do, is to send new position of items, through AJAX and all this should happen, when I 'drop' the item.
So this is my 'inventory' these are divs and I have images in these divs, when I move it, it should make the AJAX call. I only get the 500 (Internal Server Error) in Chrome console

```
$index=1;
            foreach ($inventories as $inventory) {
                if($inventory->id_w==null){
                    echo '<div id="policko'.$index.'" class="inventar" data-hasPicture="false" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>';
                    $index++;
                }else{
                   echo '<div id="policko'.$index.'" class="inventar" data-hasPicture="true" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
                <img src="/images/coin.png" class="obrazek" data-position='.$index.' id='.$inventory->position.' draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
                </div>';
                $index++;
                }
            }
```

Then I call the AJAX setup is script

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

And finally, there is the function for updating the inventory

```
    function updateInventory(itemId,position)
{
    var characterInventoryID={!! json_encode($character->id) !!};
    $.ajax({
  url: '/updateInventory',
  method: 'PUT',
  data: { itemID: itemID,characterInventoryID:characterInventoryID, position:position, _token: '{{csrf_token()}}' },
  dataType: 'json'
});
}
```

Route

```
Route::put('/updateInventory','InventoryController@updateInventory');
```

And the controller function, here I find row with current position and old position and I switch them

```
public function updateInventory(Request $request){
    if(request()->ajax()){
        $pos=$request->position;
        $idItem=$request->itemID;
        $charID=$request->characterInventoryID;
        $where = ['id_c' => $charID, 'position' => $pos];
        $whereOld = ['id_c' => $charID, 'position' => $idItem];
        $idi = Inventory::where($where)->first()->id;
        $idiOld = Inventory::where($whereOld)->first()->id;
        $i=Inventory::find($idi);
        $iOld=Inventory::find($idiOld);
        $iOld->position=$i->position;
        $i->position=$pos;
        $i->save();
        $iOld->save();
    }

}
```

Hope that this is all

Answer (score 1):

ajax doesn't have method option, you can and pass _method as data
Try this code :

```
function updateInventory(itemId,position)
{
    var characterInventoryID={!! json_encode($character->id) !!};
    $.ajax({
    url: '/updateInventory',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { _method:'PUT', itemID: itemID,characterInventoryID:characterInventoryID, position:position, _token: '{{csrf_token()}}' },
    dataType: 'json'
    });
}
```

Comment: This shows the same error, but there is written app.js:1 POST http://zjgame.test/updateInventory 500 (Internal Server Error) instead of PUT

Answer (score 0):

OK so the problem was, that my position was null, so in the controller, it couldn't find anything and that was the error.